# How to access to a specific PictureBox.EventHandler that was created programmatically?

Tags: c#

I am making a Scorebar from 1-10 where every number is one picture of a small grey cube.
Like this:

⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛ (This would be a score of 5)

Now I want to change the cube images to green ones, when the MouseDown Event is triggered, but I don't know who to tell the program.
[Pic of Scorebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6wCr.jpg)

```
private void BtnDebug_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int xPos = 200;
            int yPos = 100;
            PictureBox[] ScoreGameplay = new PictureBox[100];

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                ScoreGameplay[i] = new PictureBox();
                ScoreGameplay[i].Name = "ScoreGameplay" + i;
                ScoreGameplay[i].Size = new Size(18, 18);
                ScoreGameplay[i].Location = new Point(xPos, yPos);
                ScoreGameplay[i].Image = Image.FromFile(@"img\icons\score_empty.png");
                ScoreGameplay[i].MouseEnter += new EventHandler(Score_MouseEnter);
                ScoreGameplay[i].MouseLeave += new EventHandler(Score_MouseLeave);
                ScoreGameplay[i].MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Score_MouseDown);

                this.Controls.Add(ScoreGameplay[i]);

                xPos += 18;
            }
```

This part works without an issue, but here we go:

```
    private void Score_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is PictureBox pBox)
        {
            // ???
        }
    }
```

How do I tell know which Index of the Array in BtnDebug_Click has triggered the MouseDown?
For example:
The 7th PictureBox has been clicked; now I want to change the images from PictureBoxes 1-7 to the green ones.

Anyone has a smart solution for this?

Comment: A cheap way to do that is put the index number in the PictureBox.Tag property so it's identifiable.

Comment: You realise you already have the index in your name? Just drop `ScoreGameplay` from the name and you are left with the index you have specified here: `ScoreGameplay[i].Name = "ScoreGameplay" + i;`

Comment: @RandRandom indeed.. and it's not even necessary to drop it. The controls are consistently named and number less than 10 so an alphameric comparison of the name is possible e.g. pulling the .Name of the clicked PB, and looping `foreach(var pb in ScoreGameplay.Where(x => x.Name <= clickedPb.Name)) pb.Image = ...`

Comment: @CaiusJard - there are thousands ways to do it, as already got metioned Tag, Name - but also OP could check at which position the sender is in the array or in the Controls collection, instead of a method OP could use a local method and capture the index, instead of a simple array OP could have used a dictionary to store index and control, OP could have inherited from PictureBox and create a CustomPictureBox with an index member, and many many more possible solutions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can do that

```cs
private void BtnDebug_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int xPos = 200;
     int yPos = 100;
     PictureBox[] ScoreGameplay = new PictureBox[100];

     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
          ScoreGameplay[i] = new PictureBox();
          ScoreGameplay[i].Name = $"ScoreGameplay{i}";
          ScoreGameplay[i].Size = new Size(18, 18);
          ScoreGameplay[i].Location = new Point(xPos, yPos);
          ScoreGameplay[i].Image = Image.FromFile(@"img\icons\score_empty.png");
          ScoreGameplay[i].MouseEnter += new EventHandler(Score_MouseEnter);
          ScoreGameplay[i].MouseLeave += new EventHandler(Score_MouseLeave);
          ScoreGameplay[i].MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Score_MouseDown);

          this.Controls.Add(ScoreGameplay[i]);

          xPos += 18;
     }
}
```

and in `Score_MouseDown`

```cs
private void Score_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string imageName = ((PictureBox)sender).Name; // get the name of the clicked image
    string imageIndex = imageName.Substring(13); // get the text after 13 chars
}
```